# readline inserts a line break before the prompt in the R console

Tags: r

How can I get a user keyboard input on the current line of the R console?
I have prior output from cat and now want a `readline(prompt="")` in the same line.
I.e. there should be no line break before the prompt.

I have tried `cat("Dummy") ; readline("\r Type sth: ")` to no avail.

I cannot include "Dummy" in the prompt call as this is supposed to be a two step process (Some info in the console, prompt user input, more info in the same line, prompt second user input).

*Edit*: I came up with something that technically works but is not elegant:

```
{
cat("\014") # clear the entire console
p1 <- readline("prompt1: ")
cat("\014") # clear again, then repeat previous text
p2 <- readline(paste0("promt1: ", p1, ". prompt2: "))
}
```

A variant without clearing the console is still wanted.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if you are including this in a function named `func`, then when the user types in and sees: `> func()`, you want this to be erased/overwritten with `Type sth: `. Is that correct? (BTW: `readLine` (upper-L), could not find function, do you mean `readline` (lower-L)`?)

Comment: yup, lowercase L - changed it in the question. `Tpe sth` should be appended to the existing line.

Comment: When you type in the function, you have to hit enter to get the interpreter to parse and execute what you typed. This by itself adds a CR (and LF) before the interpreter even gets a chance at it. So I don't think what you're asking is feasible for most (if not all) R IDEs (e.g., RStudio desktop/web-client, emacs/ess, Jupyter). Why precisely do you want this behavior? It seems a little esoteric and perhaps (I'm stretching here) an aesthetic-only thing.

Comment: It's actually to test learning progress: the question is shown, upon ENTER the answer as well, and in the last step, the subjective assessment of success is recorded.
For now I'm sticking with clearing the console because the rest is a question of aesthetics indeed. 
Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem of unwanted break line with `readline` ? I have the same problem

Comment: No, I used the workaround in the question. The reason likely lies in the source code: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af9a038e/src/main/scan.c#L1016-L1025